# One click download on wordpress works in chrome and safari, would like it to work in firefox and mobile as well

Tags: html, wordpress, download

On my wordpress site I have a download button that users click and it downloads a file from amazon S3 (through the public link). When clicking that button on firefox, IE, (chrome and safari work fine), and mobile phones it takes the user to a new window streaming the mp3 instead of downloading it. How can I change the below code to work in all browsers, and if possible mobile phones as well. It is only mp3s all from amazon s3. rwmb_meta is the plugin that created the custom post type, and the 'file' is the field I put the amazon s3 link into.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[audio src="' . rwmb_meta('file') .'"]' ); ?>
<a class="file-download" href="<?php echo rwmb_meta('file'); ?>" download></a>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code?

```
<a href="http://test.com/path/to/my/file.mp3" download="true">download</a>
```

This will work on all browsers.

Comment: Tried that before as well, and everything stays the same :(
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[audio src="' . rwmb_meta('file') .'"]' ); ?>
<a class="file-download" href="<?php echo rwmb_meta('file'); ?>" download="true"></a>